# list comprehension with substring replacement not working as intended

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list as follows:

```
alist = ['xx_comb', 'xx_combined', 'xxx_rrr', '123_comb']
```

I want to replace `all occurrences` of `'_comb'` with `'_eeee'` .
But not `'xx_combined'`. Only if the word `ends with` `'_comb'`, then the replacement should happen.

I tried

```
[sub.replace('_comb', '_eeee') for sub in alist if '_combined' not in sub)]
```

But this does not work.

Comment: `alist = [sub.replace('_comb', '_eeee') for sub in alist if '_combined' not in sub]`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle: like OP's attempt (after the correcting syntax error) that also removes items that contain `_combined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Only if the word ends with _comb, then the replacement should occurs.*

This is job for `.endswith` not `in` (is substring), also you should use ternary `if` rather than comprehension `if` which do filtering. That is:

```
alist = ['xx_comb', 'xx_combined', 'xxx_rrr', '123_comb']
result = [i.replace('_comb', '_eeee') if i.endswith('_comb') else i for i in alist]
print(result)  # ['xx_eeee', 'xx_combined', 'xxx_rrr', '123_eeee']
```

Answer (score 2):

The way your condition is written means that any value with `_combined` in it is not in your output list. Instead, you need to make the replace conditional on `_combined` not being in the value:

```
alist = ['xx_comb', 'xx_combined', 'xxx_rrr', '123_comb']
print([sub.replace('_comb', '_eeee') if '_combined' not in sub else sub for sub in alist])
```

Output:

```
['xx_eeee', 'xx_combined', 'xxx_rrr', '123_eeee']
```

Based on the wording of your question though, you might be better off using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20sub#re.sub) to replace `_comb` at the end of the string with `_eeee`:

```
import re

alist = ['xx_comb', 'xx_combined', 'xxx_rrr', '123_comb']
print([re.sub(r'_comb$', '_eeee', sub) for sub in alist])
```

Output:

```
['xx_eeee', 'xx_combined', 'xxx_rrr', '123_eeee']
```